# Getting 403 error which lacks further detail

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-dotnet-client

Am using the Cloud Storage JSON API. Using a JSON certificate file downloaded from Google Cloud Platform console. And of interest, I am running a sample which worked fine when I first write it a couple months ago.

According to 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes
the explanation is "This is an example of an error response you receive if you try to list the buckets of a non-existent project or one in which you don't have permission to list buckets."

I don't believe that anything has been changed on this project. It is a project I created for development testing. Any thoughts/ideas?

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Added: I just updated to latest dotnet client libs and still get same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had a some point accidentally deleted the IAM for the service account. After adding back in, the API call succeeded.